# Any continuous func. from (0,1) to (0,1) has a fixed point.Is it true?

Tags: real-analysis

Any continuous func. from (0,1) to (0,1) has a fixed point.Is it true?

if not $f(x)\neq x$ for all x.Define g=f-x/(|f-x|).then range of g is $\{-1,1\}$ contradiction to cont.image of connected set connected

so  i think true.is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is only true if you include the endpoints. Counterexample: $f(x)=\frac12x$. What's wrong with your proof is that in the example, the range of $g$ is just $\{-1\}$, which is connected.